# Why delete it's working in another variable?

Tags: javascript

Why delete is working in another data ?

```
      this.Line = [];
      this.showDataForm = [{
        'name': 'BTC',
        'data': [1,2,3,4]
        'chart': 'linemulti'
      }]

      for (var index=0; index < this.showDataForm.length; index++) {
        if ( this.showDataForm[index].chart === "linemulti" ) { // for merge chart
          this.Line.push(this.showDataForm[index]);
        }
      }
      
      for (var key=0; key < this.Line.length; key++){
          delete this.Line[key].chart;
      }
```

I try to show:

```
console.log(this.showDataForm);

[{'name':'BTC','data':[1,2,3,4]}]
```

why delete is working in this.showDataForm ?
how to fix ?

Comment: You're referencing the same object when you delete and when you console.log

Comment: No I delete this.Line `delete this.Line[key].chart;` but it's delete this.showDataForm.

Comment: It's the same thing - see my answer for more info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `delete` on the item in the `Line` array, it is just a *reference* to the original object in `showDataForm`.

If you wanted to instead *copy* a new item to the `Line` array you can use the spread operator `...` as is shown below. This means the original object is not affected when you delete one of the keys:

```js
this.Line = [];
this.showDataForm = [{
  'name': 'BTC',
  'data': [1,2,3,4],
  'chart': 'linemulti'
}]

for (var index=0; index < this.showDataForm.length; index++) {
  if ( this.showDataForm[index].chart === "linemulti" ) { // for merge chart
    this.Line.push({...this.showDataForm[index]});
  }
}

for (var key=0; key < this.Line.length; key++){
    delete this.Line[key].chart;
}

console.log(this.showDataForm)
```